# Unity 2d dropping more then 1 bomb

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

when I instsiate the bomb it makes more then one sometimes up to 3bombs at once I want it to make 1 bomb not 2 or 3 bombs. 
I need a way to be sure it only use the void dropbomb once.
I'm looking forward to your help I like to say sry for the bad English and maby that point that I could have missed something important in my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlaneBombDroper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bomb;
    public GameObject bombDropPostion;
    public GameObject planePostion;
    int bombDropRandomNum;
    public float[] dropPostionsX;
    bool bombIsDroped;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        bombDropRandomNum = Random.Range(1, 3);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (bombDropRandomNum == 1 && bombIsDroped != true)
        {

            if (planePostion.transform.position.x < -2.75f && planePostion.transform.position.x > -3)
            {
                dropBomb();
            }
        }
        if (bombDropRandomNum == 2&& bombIsDroped != true)
        {
            if (planePostion.transform.position.x < -9.5 && planePostion.transform.position.x > -10)
            {
                StartCoroutine("WaitForSeconds");
                StopCoroutine("WaitForSeconds");
            }
        }

    }
    void dropBomb()
    {
        Instantiate(bomb, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
    }
    IEnumerator WaitForSeconds()
    {
        dropBomb();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Id suggest then the dropbomb does not do something if BombisDroped and on exploding of bomb you set the bombisdropped to false

Comment: ill try to that

Comment: LOL i tried it soo many times but i totally missed doing it in the fucition instead thx for the help that made it

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bombdrop function fires off a new bomb irrelevant of if there is a bomb already in action - you need to add a condition that if a bomb is firing not to run that new bomb code.  You already have the bombisdroped variable - it makes sense that if (!bombisdroped)  is then your new bombdrop function

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a flag on your update

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlaneBombDroper : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject bomb;
public GameObject bombDropPostion;
public GameObject planePostion;
int bombDropRandomNum;
public float[] dropPostionsX;
bool bombIsDroped;
private bool launchingBomb = false;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    bombDropRandomNum = Random.Range(1, 3);
}
void Update()
{
    if (!launchingBomb)
    {
        if (bombDropRandomNum == 1 && bombIsDroped != true)
        {

            if (planePostion.transform.position.x < -2.75f && planePostion.transform.position.x > -3)
            {
            dropBomb();
            }
        }
        if (bombDropRandomNum == 2&& bombIsDroped != true)
        {
            if (planePostion.transform.position.x < -9.5 && planePostion.transform.position.x > -10)
            {
                StartCoroutine("WaitForSeconds");
                StopCoroutine("WaitForSeconds");
            }
        }
    }

    void dropBomb()
    {
        launchingBomb = true;
        Instantiate(bomb, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
        launchingBomb = false;
    }
    IEnumerator WaitForSeconds()
    {
        launchingBomb = true;
        dropBomb();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```